# How do you publish status to a specific friend list?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to publish a status to a specific friend list (e.g. "family" or "best friends"). I can get the ID of the friend lists using the FB API, but I don't see a way to use this ID when publishing the status.

With a group, I can just publish to the group ID (https://graph.facebook.com/groupID/feed). But this doesn't seem to work for a friend list.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick:

```
curl -F 'access_token=your_access_token' -F 'message=your_message' -F \
  "privacy={'value':'CUSTOM','friends':'SOME_FRIENDS','allow':'your_list'}" \
  https://graph.facebook.com/your_id/feed
```